# Symfony use JMS Serializer with JsonResponse

Tags: json, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

In a Symfony application is it possible to use the JMS serializer when calling `JsonResponse()` on a controller`?

```
$response = new ApiResponse(ApiResponse::STATUS_SUCCESS);
return new JsonResponse($response); // <-- I would like to use the JMS serializer
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of symfony 3 you can use this:

```
    $json = $this->get("serializer")->serialize($response, 'json');
    return new JsonResponse($json, 200, [], true);
```

In case of symfony 2 you don't have the last argument, but you can use a standart Reponse and specify the content type:

```
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Comment: What does the last `true` parameter do? I think that doing so would re-encode the whole response.

Comment: I seems that that argument exists only on the 3.x branches :(
I am using Symfony v2.8:
http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.html#method___construct
http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.html#method___construct

Comment: Have a look here please:
[link](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/288#issuecomment-71333964)
"I had a similar problem. It's really inconvenient that you have no way to tell to the JsonResponse that you're data is already in JSON. So the only way is to use the Response object dans set the headers to JSON:"

$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

Comment: Yes please update your answer with a complete example with the standard response object and I will accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah sure. I did so :)

Comment: @StockBreak Could you please mark my answer as a correct one. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For Symfony 4+ the DI for serialization can be used this way if `autowire = true`

*In Symfony 4 the **autowire** is already set **true** as default.*

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

/**
 * ... anything
 *
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public action(SerializerInterface $serializer) {
    return new JsonResponse($serializer->serialize($response, 'json'), 200, [], true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And since Symfony 5 one can simply call `json` function.
Under the [hood](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v5.0.0/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/AbstractController.php#L168) it uses the symfony `serializer` service.

```
public function index(): Response {
    $data = ... some json data
    return $this->json($data);
}
```